# Apache: client and server on same VPS

Tags: node.js, apache

I am wondering if it is okay to serve both, client and api under one domain?
For example: `index.html` at `my-vps.supplier.net` and `my-vps.supplier.net:3000` for api served by NodeJS?

Is it even okay to expose api in such way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache reverse proxy (or another balancing technology) to expose the api on port 80 but on a different domain or on the same domain but under a different path.

For apache Reverse Proxy: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html

For HAPropxy: http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.4/intro.html